# Problems with unlinking python using homebrew

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew, unlink

I want to uninstall python from my Mac since I have some troubles with it and want to reinstall it.

Thus, I've tried to use `brew unlink python`. However, the console throws the following error, when I try that:

> Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4... Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python

Now I'm not able to use python due to the mentioned troubles, but I'm not able to reinstall it either. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symlink appears to be missing. Reproduced:

```
% rm /usr/local/opt/python
rm: remove symbolic link '/usr/local/opt/python'? y

% brew unlink python
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4... Error: No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /usr/local/opt/python

% brew reinstall  --force python
==> Reinstalling python
Error: python 3.7.4 is already installed
To install 3.7.4, first run `brew unlink python`.
```

Recreate the link...

```
% ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 /usr/local/opt/python
'/usr/local/opt/python' -> '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3'
```

and you should be able to unlink or uninstall:

```
% brew unlink python
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4... 22 symlinks removed

% brew uninstall python
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4... (3,865 files, 60MB)
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following error: "Error: python 3.7.4 is already installed". However, if I type "python3" in the console it says "command not found". So brew "thinks", python3 is installed, although I can't use it. What's the problem here? And how can I really reinstall python?